# Indexing the memory of a double pointer in C

Tags: c

In the piece of code below, what does the line: p[1]=p[0] entail? Does that mean that the data allocated to the p[0] is in the same address as p[1]? Also how is it even possible to utilize indexing when no memory has been allocated to each specific index of p? The code:

```
    int i,j; 
    int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *)); 
    p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); 
    p[1] = p[0]; 
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
            p[i][j] = i + j; 
    printf("%d",p[0][0]); 
    return 0;
```

I thank you in advance for sharing with me a part of your wisdom!

Comment: `p[1]` and `p[0]` now point to the same memory.

Comment: What Paul said. To copy memory, use [`memcpy`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/memcpy.html).

Comment: @marktheodore If you found any of the answers useful remember to upvote them, and accept the best one.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's trying to create a 2D matrix that is 2x2 in size (as `p[row][column]`). However, only 1 row is actually allocated. Then `p[1] = p[0];` means row 1 is pointing back to row 0. Essentially it's a 2x2 matrix where the both rows are identically the same.

This allocates two "pointers to a pointers" which allow you to use the row index `p[row]`, but the rows still point to garbage at this point:

```
int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
```

Then the actual row memory is allocated that allows you to use the column index `p[row][column]`:

```
p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

The correct way to achieve an actual 2x2 matrix would be to allocate space for all 4 serialized values first like this:

```
p[0] = (int *)malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```

Then have row 1 point to the 3rd element:

```
p[1]= &p[0][2];
```

This is not to say you should write your code this way (there are far better ways), it is just an explanation of the fishy code you provided.

Comment: Furthermore the for loops seem wrong. it will write `p[0][0] = 0 ` then `p[1][0] = 1` but `p[1][0]`and `p[1][0]` point to the same memory

Comment: To have row 1 point to the 3rd element you should write `p[1]= &p[0][2];`though you are doing dirty tricks and this is not clean.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sure, I fixed it, but the entire code is fishy and dangerous to begin with. I'm only answering the vague question that was asked with some example of why it seems very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## Q1 and 2 :

p is defined as :

```C
int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
```

Then, `p[0]` and `p[1]` are `int *` so when you do `p[1] = p[0]`, you are assigning to `p[1]` the same value than `p[0]` **Careful, the pointers are assagned, not the value that they are pointing to, so if after this you change `p[1][i]`, `p[0][i]` will also be changed**

To better present this, I will try to draw the memory:

Before the assignment:

variable | Memory address

p[0]----points to----> 0xXXXX   (x an arbitrary number)

p[1]----points to----> 0xYYYY   (y an arbitrary number)

After the assignment:

p[0]----points to----> 0xXXXX

p[1]----points to----> 0xXXXX

## Q3:

As `p[1]=p[0]` and you previously allocated `p[0]` , then `p[1]` points to the zone in memory that was alocated with :

```C
p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

Therefore there is not any issue. If you remove the `p[1] = p[0]` line, it should thow a segfault.

Answer (score -1):

To create a 2x2 matrix, you should do:

```
int i; 
int **p = malloc(2 * sizeof(int *)); 
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    p[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: This is a more generic/cleaner way to create a 2x2 matrix, but that wasn't either of the two questions which were asked. Also it's not as efficient as my answer which allocates all the "serialized" memory in one contiguous malloc.